# A simple COPY statement in PostgreSQL 8.4

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.4

I am trying to copy a table's data to a file. I have a small database table in the local windows machine and this code has no problems. When I use this in the development environment (still windows, different database), I get an error.

My standard_conforming_strings is currently off.

This query:

```
COPY some_table TO 'C:\\temp\\test.csv' WITH CSV HEADER;
```

Gives this error:

```
WARNING:  nonstandard use of \\ in a string literal
LINE 1: COPY t_table TO 'C:\\temp\\test.csv' WITH CSV HEADER;
                      ^
HINT:  Use the escape string syntax for backslashes, e.g., E'\\'.


ERROR:  relative path not allowed for COPY to file


********** Error **********

ERROR: relative path not allowed for COPY to file
SQL state: 42602
```

I have tried:

```
'C:\temp\test.csv'
'C:\\temp\\test.csv'
'C:/temp/test.csv'
'C:\/temp\/test.csv'
```

And in all my test, the caret ^ in the error message points at ^'C:.

Comment: `'C:\temp\test.csv'` should work assuming `standard_conforming_strings = on` which is the default. `'C:/temp/test.csv'` should also work. Do you get the exactly the same error message for all versions?

Comment: Yes, @a_horse_with_no_name. Could it be a database setting preventing me from doing this?

Comment: The docs says:  Beginning in PostgreSQL 9.1, the default is on (prior releases defaulted to off). I'm using 8.4. Could this be the culprit? If I change this, will it have a negative effect on my database? Thanks! Edit: It is off!

Comment: That will only influence the warning ("*nonstandard use of...*") that you get. But even with this set to `off` using `'C:/temp/test.csv'` should work just fine. I don't have any 8.4 around any more to test this, sorry

Comment: `'C:/temp/test.csv'` or `E'C:\\temp\\test.csv'` should be fine. Are you using native Windows PostgreSQL, though, or a Cygwin build? Please show the output of `SELECT version()`.

Comment: Hi again, @CraigRinger. Here it is: "PostgreSQL 8.4.22 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4), 32-bit"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using PostgreSQL on *linux* not Windows. Just using a Windows client.

`COPY` is a server side command. It expects a path on the server. That file is on your Windows client PC so the server cannot access it.

Use `\copy` from `psql` instead. Or use PgAdmin's CSV importer.

(Newer PostgreSQL versions would give you a `HINT` about this in the error message.)